# How Can implement Twilio Voice Call (One to One Call ) Not Programmatically?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

Looking to make one on one voice call using Twilio API through integration in phone app. User should be able to. Login with registered Twilio number and be able to call other Twilio numbers within the account or any outside phone number within USA

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds like you are looking for the [Programmable Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk) which is available for [iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/ios) or [Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/ios). The Programmable Voice SDK allows you to build an application which can make app to app or app to phone calls using Twilio Programmable Voice.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks philnash i'll check it and in there have any query i'l take your help